# (Oracle)How to test user function convenently without making another table

Tags: oracle, function

To test function 'test2' below, I have tried like these.

```
SELECT test2('A') FROM DUAL;SELECT test2('C') FROM DUAL;SELECT test2('E') FROM DUAL;
```

But is there a convenient way to do this at once ? (without making another table)

I guess query might look like this
SELECT test2(p.c1) FROM ( .... ) p ?

Table and function as below

```
    CREATE TABLE T2 (
    C1 VARCHAR2(1),
    C2 NUMBER
    );

    INSERT INTO T2  VALUES ('A',1);
    INSERT INTO T2  VALUES ('B',4);
    INSERT INTO T2  VALUES ('C',3);
    INSERT INTO T2  VALUES ('D',2);
    INSERT INTO T2  VALUES ('E',4);

    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test2
    (p1 IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN NUMBER AS V_VALUE NUMBER;
    BEGIN
    SELECT(
        SELECT C2 
        FROM T2

    WHERE C1=p1)
INTO V_VALUE
FROM DUAL;
RETURN V_VALUE;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be after something like:

```
WITH test_data AS (SELECT 'A' val FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'B' val FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'C' val FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'D' val FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'E' val FROM dual)
SELECT test2(val)
FROM   test_data;
```

Using `select ... from dual union all select ... from dual ...` is a great way of setting up temporary test data for simple tests, without needing to create extra objects to hold the data.